# JQM building pages in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

Instead of building pages in my HTML, I'd like to build in javascript, but I couldn't figured out how to do. So, I've tried to use `.trigger("create")`, which is not the case, because he keeps creating many pages. Another way I did is `append`, It works, but not the way I want, because doesn't give me Widget. But, It should render, right? Or there is better way to do?

Html

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="button" onclick="goToMenu()">Next</div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">   
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var menu = '<div data-theme="a" data-role="header"> \n' +
'<a data-role="button" onclick="" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a> \n' +
'<h3> Header</h3> \n' +
'</div> \n' +
'<div data-role="content"> \n' +
'</div> \n' +
'</div>';

function goToMenu() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
        transition: "flow"
    });
    $('#page2').append(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to restructure your code a lil bit.

1. It's not advisable to use `data-role="button"` on a `div`. Use it on `a` or on `button` tag.
2. You'll have to put all the code for dynamic generation of page in the `goToMenu` function. Append it, then use `changePage`.
3. The use of `onclick` is not advisable. Use the jQuery way of event delegation.

Here's the markup :

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
        <button id="nextPageLink">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2"></div>
```

Here's the JavaScript :

```
//pageinit event of page1
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function () {
    //click event for button
    $(this).on("click", "button", function () {
        //create HTML
        var menu = '<div data-theme="a" data-role="header">' +
            '<a data-role="button" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a> ' +
            '<h3> Header</h3>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div data-role="content">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        //append "menu" to #page2
        $(menu).appendTo("#page2");
        //changePage to redirect to #page2
        $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
    });
});
```

And here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/3uybD/